# Is there any way to tell what color an item is dyed?

Tags: diablo-iii

I picked up a new chest armor from the auction house, and it's a strange shade of blue that I've never seen, and it doesn't seem to match other items from its visual tier in terms of color.

I *assume* that it's dyed, but I don't see any reference to this on the item itself, and I'm the kind of visual OCD that I'd like to dye the rest of my items to match it. Is there any way to confirm which blue it is short of random guessing and checking?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but there is in fact the following workaround!

Equip the item, leave the game and logout (this step is required for your profile to be updated).  Then log in at http://battle.net, click on Diablo III, navigate to your profile and select the character who has the item equipped.  If the item is dyed, then a small icon should be visible at the bottom-left of its equipment slot; hover over it to find out the colour.

[image: Screenshot]
The URL should look like this:
`http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/profile/rtsAlaran-<yourbattletag>/hero/<heroid>`
See the breadcrumb-line at the top too.

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, I don't think there is a mechanic in the game to identify the exact dye color that was applied. Although and arduous task, you may have to just sit through a youtube video that displays the dyes associated with your class and match up the name.

**Males:**

[Monk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lcdKi8bujgs)

[Demon Hunter](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7NnVjJj7ICs&feature=relmfu)

[Barbarian](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VX0JnktB-oI&feature=relmfu)

[Witch Doctor](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2qzicunMJU)

[Wizard](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LajX9CrRPho&feature=relmfu)

**Females:**

[Monk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w6ohWCTGKns&feature=relmfu)

[Demon Hunter](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5oWf4dM6Lg&feature=relmfu)

[Barbarian](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhGjcpnzCMY&feature=relmfu)

[Witch Doctor](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c23K95QDyrw&feature=relmfu)

[Wizard](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3QXXUDb12hM&feature=relmfu)

Alternativley if you don't care for the blue anyway you could try a dye remover. Maybe that is the color the armor is by default. Might be worth a test for the love of *science*.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I would do to determine a dye color:

- Screenshot the questionable item. You may want a front and back screenshot depending on which armor piece it is
- Use a dye-remover and see if any colors change.

  - If it doesn't, the item is not dyed and is that color naturally.
  - If it does, you now know what color changed so go on to next step.
- Refer to your screenshot(s) and compare the color of the changed part with the [Diablo III dye list](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/dye/). You should have only a few viable options, so go find those dyes and re-dye the item and see if it looks the same as a Screenshot.

  Of course, you could also try comparing the color with something like this [YouTube Dye Palette Playlist](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL67C72812EB24AC40), but I'm usually lazy and don't want to look through a lot of videos :)
- And if you still can't figure it out, take another screenshot and post both the before and after screenshot on [Gaming.SE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) and ask them for an answer :)

Comment: Well, but this is destructive. After the dye is removed, you know that it WAS dyed, but now, that information is invalid.